# How to resolve npm ERR! Missing script: "sonar" while executing npm run sonar

Tags: jenkins, npm, sonarqube, pipeline

I got error npm ERR! Missing script: "sonar" while executing jenkins pipeline job with sonarqube and jenkins integration. Below is the error details.Please anyone got how to solve this error.
thanks in advance.

```
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\sonarqube-pipeline>npm run sonar 
npm ERR! Missing script: "sonar"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-25T12_42_55_010Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Do you have a `sonar` script in the `scripts` section of `package.json`?

Comment: Here is my package.json file

Comment: {
  "name": "sample-node-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample Node.js Project",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Adem Cemil YALCIN",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Comment: You don't have a `sonar` script, so `npm run sonar` won't do anything.

Comment: Here is my jenkins pipeline script piece of code .What i have to write in sonar script.it is failing now in npm install.                               
      stage('SonarQube analysis'){
            steps{
     script{
      nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'nodejs19.1.0'){
         bat 'npm install'
      withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube 8.9.10'){
     bat 'npm install sonarqube-scanner --save-dev'
     bat 'npm run sonar'
                }
               }   
              }     
            }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks joe clay,

Now it is working fine.After adding below code in sonar-project.js

"sonar": "node sonar-project.js"
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"

Thanks for your response it was so much helpful.